# Does a +1 shield allow me to add 3 to my Dex saves when using the second benefit of Shield Master?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, feats

If I have a [+1 shield](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/shield-1) and the [Shield Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/shield-master) feat (PHB, p. 170), can I add 3 to my Dex saving throw when I use the second benefit of Shield Master?

> If you aren’t incapacitated, you can add your shield’s AC bonus to any Dexterity saving throw you make against a spell or other harmful effect that targets only you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Yes, it does

No distinction is made between the normal bonus to AC and the bonus as a result of the magic item. They are simply bonuses to AC. Since both are part of your "shield's AC bonus", they are both included.

Regular shield:

> A shield is made from wood or metal and is carried in one hand. Wielding a shield increases your Armor Class by 2.

Shield +1:

> While holding this shield, you have a +1 bonus to AC. This bonus is in addition to the shield's normal bonus to AC.

Notice that neither of these bonuses are made distinct by a title like "shield bonus". They are just bonuses to AC that come from the shield.

Comment: I think the hangup is "*You* have +1 bonus to AC..." So is the shield's AC bonus +3? or +2 and an extra +1 that doesn't apply to the feat. Not saying I disagree.

Comment: @Jason_c_o Oh I got it now. Didn't realize where the confusion was coming frkm

Comment: Further, if +1 shields did not benefit the Shield Master feat, the Shield Master feat description would presumably be written as "If you aren’t incapacitated, **you can add +2** to any Dexterity saving throw you make against a spell or other harmful effect that targets only you."

Comment: @PinkSweetener see my comment on [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/132479/41726) for why that logical conclusion doesn't quite follow. There could be other reasons to make the wording more general

Answer (score 6):

#### The +1 is part of the shield's AC bonus for this purpose

Unlike in previous editions of D&D, 5e has very simplified [shield rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/shield):

> Wielding a shield increases your Armor Class by 2.

Naturally, some shields are special; the +1 shield mentioned increases your AC by 3 instead. However, if "special" shields that give different AC bonuses aren't intended to affect the benefit of Shield Master, then Shield Master could simply be worded as "add 2" rather than "add your shield's AC bonus". Since the wording of the feat implies that some shields give a different bonus, and magic shields are the most common reason I know of that a shield would give a different bonus, I conclude that the different bonus from a magic shield is intended to apply.

Comment: While this is a potential cause for thr wording, it neglects the possibility that they were simply trying to future proof the feat. In fact the Players Handbook wad release before the Dungeon Master's Guide introduced magic shields. A non-magic shield with a particular quality could grant a default +3 bonus in a later book, and the feat would not have to be updated. In this way, your argument isn't entirely complete as it doesn't justify the placement of the +1 AC as part of the bonus referenced by the feat.

Answer (score -4):

You should note that it's not every dexterity save. It must be an attack that targets ONLY you. So no dragon's breath because it's an AoE attack. You should discuss with your DM whether or not you are allowed to use it from all dexterity saves

Comment: Hi, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here, and there's also the [help centre](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. While you are correct, this seems more like a comment on an existing post that doesn't really address the heart of the issue the OP is asking about. Answers here should really be for addressing the main question. Once you have enough reputation (50, I believe?) you will be able to comment under any post to suggest improvements to someone else's answer. Or, you can add to your own answer here to address the OP's main question in full.